# Vectrosity: Make a dashed line appear to rotate with the same speed across resolutions

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I am using Vectrosity to draw some shapes and I have come across a problem I'm unable to solve. This is not an issue with Vectrosity, but rather a hole in my knowledge. I hope someone here can help me get this right! :)

[image: both the red bar and dashed line is rotating]

The red bar in the image is moving around the circle using a script that in short looks like this:

```
// Make the red bar move around the dashed circle
float dist = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (dist > 1) 
        dist = dist - 1;

    dist += Time.deltaTime * (Mathf.Abs(speed) / 8);
    Vector3 point = line.GetPoint3D01(dist);
    redbar.localPosition = pos;
}
```

So far so good - this works exactly like I want it to.

The issue I am having is with the dashed line itself. **I need it to move with the same speed as the red bar**. I can make it work by setting a fixed value for the speed for a given resolution, but as soon as the screen resolution changes, the dashed line no longer move with the same speed as the red bar.

I have tried to figure out a formula that sets the textureOffset dynamically - without any success. The dashed line is "moved" by changing the textureOffset like this:

```
// Make dashed line appear to rotate
void Update()
{
    dashedline.textureOffset = -Time.time * (speed * 4.8f) % 1f;
}
```

How can I make the dashed line appear to rotate with the exact same speed as the red bar *across all screen resolutions*?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a resolution problem, its a DPI problem. Line width is in pixels, so a 5 pixel line at 72dpi will be wider than a 5 pixel line at 300dpi. There's no way to query DPI, so you'd probably want to set different widths for different devices.

Comment: Ok.. if that is for sure, then we can use DPI I guess. And it is indeed possible to get the DPI:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html